# android No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: android

I have changed compile SDK version and target sdk version from 25 to 26 and changed buildToolsVersion from 25.0.1 to 26.0.2. While compiling the android application getting below error.

> values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

This is a android cordova project.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: okay then you want to change `26` to `27` and `26.0.2` to `27.0.2` and it's finally work for you

Comment: I tried with above mentioned changes but same error.

Comment: paste your `gradle(app)`

Comment: Below I am giving the changes  I have done as part of this:
APP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 26
    APP_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "26.0.2"
    APP_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 19
    APP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26

Cradle wrapper properties

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Support library 
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2”

Comment: Actually I mentioned my issue is not solved.

Comment: follow this 2 linke https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13088 **OR** https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/882